# Matlab error compiling C files with mex

Tags: c, matlab, x86-64, mex

i'm trying to compile a program for image deblurring. 
I try to run

```
mex apply_blur_kernel_mex.c
```

where the file apply_blur_kernel_mex.c have the following code

```
#include <mex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <matrix.h>
#include "ow_homography.h"
...
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
...
compute_homography_matrix(Ksharp, &theta_list[k*3], invKblurry, H);
...
}
```

The problem is in the function compute_homography_matrix that is in another file ow_homography.h

```
#ifndef OW_HOMOGRAPHY_H
#define OW_HOMOGRAPHY_H

#include "ow_mat3.h"

INLINE void compute_homography_matrix(const double *Ksharp, const double *theta, const double *invKblurry, double *H) {
    double R[9];
    /* Compute homography */
    cp3(invKblurry,H);
    rot3(theta[0],theta[1],theta[2],R);
    mmip3(R,H);
   mmip3(Ksharp,H);
}
```

This last operations (cp3, rot3...) are in another file ow_mat3.h that contains all the operations for the program.
So when i try to call

```
mex apply_blur_kernel_mex.c
```

i have the following problem:

```
Error using mex
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_compute_homography_matrix", referenced from: 
       mexFunction in apply_blur_kernel_mex.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions to solve this problem? 
Thank you all.

Comment: the function described in your error mesage is prefixed with an underscore while the code in your example is not

Comment: gcc has a nice `-fleading-underscore` to force underscore on symbols. Dunno about clang.

Answer (score 0):

http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline

> C compatibility C99 inline functions
>
> By default, Clang builds C code in GNU C11 mode, so it uses standard
>   C99 semantics for the inline keyword. These semantics are different
>   from those in GNU C89 mode, which is the default mode in versions of
>   GCC prior to 5.0. For example, consider the following code:
>
> ```
> inline int add(int i, int j) { return i + j; }
>
> int main() {   int i = add(4, 5);   return i; }
> ```
>
> In C99, inline means that a function's definition is provided only for
>   inlining, and that there is another definition (without inline)
>   somewhere else in the program. That means that this program is
>   incomplete, because if add isn't inlined (for example, when compiling
>   without optimization), then main will have an unresolved reference to
>   that other definition. Therefore we'll get a (correct) link-time error
>   like this:
>
> ```
> Undefined symbols:   "_add", referenced from:
>       _main in cc-y1jXIr.o
> ```
>
> By contrast, GNU C89 mode (used by default in older versions of GCC)
>   is the C89 standard plus a lot of extensions. C89 doesn't have an
>   inline keyword, but GCC recognizes it as an extension and just treats
>   it as a hint to the optimizer.
>
> **There are several ways to fix this problem:**
>
> 1) Change add to a static inline function. This is usually the right solution if only one translation unit needs to use the function.
>   static inline functions are always resolved within the translation
>   unit, so you won't have to add a non-inline definition of the function
>   elsewhere in your program.
>
> 2) Remove the inline keyword from this definition of add. The inline keyword is not required for a function to be inlined, nor does it
>   guarantee that it will be. Some compilers ignore it completely. Clang
>   treats it as a mild suggestion from the programmer.
>
> 3) Provide an external (non-inline) definition of add somewhere else in your program. The two definitions must be equivalent!
>
> 4)Compile in the GNU C89 dialect by adding -std=gnu89 to the set of Clang options. This option is only recommended if the program source
>   cannot be changed or if the program also relies on additional
>   C89-specific behavior that cannot be changed.
>
> All of this only applies to C code; the meaning of inline in C++ is
>   very different from its meaning in either GNU89 or C99.